# Guidance on some weird partitioning

Tags: partitioning

I'm looking to move hard drives on a computer here using the dd command (v. 20).  But before doing so, I've got some weird partition setup that I'm not sure I want to replicate, and I definitely don't understand.  I'm 'used' to a pretty standard partition setup. Would anyone be willing to tell me what I"m looking at with this setup?

The disks command shows:

1. 120g Disk with three partitions:

   - 255 mb filesystem, mounted at /boot
   - 120 gb partition 2, device /dev/sda2
   - 120 gb partition 5, device /dev/sda5
2. 112 gb block device /dev/ubuntu-vg-root
3. 8.1 gb block device /dev/ubuntu-vf/swap-1

In 1) above, the 2 120gb partitions are shown on top of each other, i.e. they look like they're consuming the same space, rther than being shown consequitively like what I'd expect (which makes sense, because the drive's only 120g, so there's definitely not 2X120g partitions.

The 'df' command shows:
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 107256856 76985900  24799520  76% /
and
/dev/sda1 used 66% mounted on /boot.

Can I get rid of this confusion, and somehow get back to a more traditional /boot on one partition, and / mounted on /sda2 or something like that?

(the underlying problem I'm solving is that I want to use dd to move to a new hard drive, then expand the partition size on the new drive.  This existing setup is causing that to not work.  So if I can get rid of, or understand what's going on with the existing, then I can do the hd upgrade).
THanksin advance.

Comment: If you don't want to keep the same partition scheme, then don't use dd. There are plenty of other ways to copy files. Use dd only when you want the destination to be identical to the source, which you don't want in this situation.

Comment: You are using the old MBR partiitoning that was used with DOS in early 1980's. Since UEFI gpt has become the new standard. Apple started when they converted to Intel, Microsoft requires gpt with all UEFI installs by vendors. Old BIOS/MBR allowed for old hardware. Linux supported gpt with BIOS boot at least in 2010 when I converted. You also are using the advanced LVM volumes. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm  I would convert to gpt, so no logical partitions. Whether you want LVM or not is up to you.